# exception message in a constructor

Tags: java, oop, exception

So I have a method that throws an IllegalStateException

```
@Override
public Value getJSONValue(String query) throws IllegalStateException {
    Value result = null; 
    JSONIter iter = obj.iterator(); 
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        Value v = iter.getNext();
        result = v;
    }
    return result; 
}//getJSONValue
```

I want to provide a message to the constructor for this exception and this is what I did. Is this a correct way of providing the message.

```
public QueryManager() {
    obj = null;
    if (obj == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("JSON Object has not been loaded");
    }
}
```

The condition for this exception is that the Object must call this method before using getJSONValue(String)

```
@Override
public void loadJSON(String JSON) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    this.obj = parser.read(JSON);
    System.out.print("MyJSONObject :" + obj.toString());
}//loadJSON
enter code here
```

Comment: The message is fine, but you'll always get the exception if you set `obj` to null beforehand.

Comment: So if I create a new QueryManager() obj is set to null right? It's only given a value after I call the loadJSON()

Comment: ........correct